# How to use Alamofire to send Form-data as in Postman

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, postman

I want to make similar ALamofire request as Postman request shown in screenshot

I ended up that POST + Alamofire UPload + appendBodyPart(#stream: NSInputStream, length: UInt64, headers: [String: String])

will be the Answer but did not find clear example how to implement it ?

I did check [this Doc.](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/1.3.1/Classes/MultipartFormData.html#/s:FC9Alamofire17MultipartFormData14appendBodyPartFS0_FT6streamCSo13NSInputStream6lengthVSs6UInt647headersGVSs10DictionarySSSS__T_)

[image: Postman screenshot]

Comment: you just send text than why u are using upload in alamofire and not post request

Comment: unfortunately I am not the backend developer , I have to use API they gave me , I think this is meant to be more secured for login

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your simple POST request with Alamofire should be like this

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http:/request.example.com", parameters: ["foo": "bar","key_1":"value_1"])
     .response { request, response, data, error in
          println(request)
          println(response)
          println(error)
      }
```

You can use `.responseJSON` , `.responseString` according to your response

Comment: thanks so much It worked , I thought this is encoded as JSON which is different from form-data

Comment: no its a simple POST request ... glad this works for u :)

Comment: @MaheshAgrawal may be some minor issue .. but without checking your code .. can't say anyhting:)

Comment: I try this, but i cant desired response, because i try with postman and i **only** got a desired response in "form-data" body!!!

Answer (score 0):

Coming from 2020 with Swift 5 and Alamofire 4.9.1, this one works for me:

```
Alamofire.request("http:/request.example.com", 
                   method: .post,
                   parameters: ["foo": "bar","key_1":"value_1"],
                   encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).response { response in
      print(response.request)
      print(response.data)
      print(response.error)
  }
```

Hope this helps someone.